# Раcширеный поиск в yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Есть три таблицы (house, apartment, land_parts). На сайте есть поиск (расширенный поиск так сказать). К примеру:

> Я хочу | (Купить, Продать, Аренда)
>   Тип Недвижимости | (Дом, Квартира, Участок земли)
>   Город | (New York, San Andreas, Vice City)

Есть соответственно три модели на каждую таблицу.

Нужно если пользователь выбирает "Тип Недвижимости" к примеру "Дом" то что бы запрос обрабатывался нужной моделью.

Получается что поле "Тип Недвижимости" не должно передаваться в форме, а должно быть как поле так сказать для выбора модели которая будет выполнять запрос.

Может кто-нибудь знает как это решить другим способом или может какой то плагин есть.

Comment: Создаёте 3 экшена поиска в контроллерах для разных моделей и при выборе определённого поля на кнопку "Найти" вешаете вызов нужного экшена.

Comment: непонятно, почему же поле "Тип Недвижимости" не должно передаваться в форме?

Comment: @Blacknife потому что я хочу что бы оно выбирало с какой моделью работать.

Comment: @SilentStorm ну так принимай этот параметр и в зависимости от него отправляй в нужную модель, только отправляй GET а не POST - так на результаты поиска будут ссылки формироваться

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите сделать это в одном экшене, то это можно решить так (я кстати не особо понял как это выглядит во вью, если там из определенных значений выбор - значит там select ):

Вы передаете в селекте некий параметр, по которому будете видеть, какую модель нужно использовать; в экшене, через switch case, просто делаете условия для существующих вариантом, а по дефолту (`default case`) какое-то исключение, чтобы значения не подменялись, ну или то, что сами захотите.

Если мы говорим о разных вещах, то вам нужно расширить свой вопрос.